# sizeof in virtual inheritancec C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int i;
};

class B: virtual public A
{
    public:
        int j;
};

class C: virtual public A
{
    public:
        int k;
};
class D: virtual public B, virtual public C
{
    public:
        int l;
};

int main()
{

    cout<<" A : "<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
    cout<<" B : "<<sizeof(B)<<endl;
    cout<<" C : "<<sizeof(C)<<endl;
    cout<<" D : "<<sizeof(D)<<endl;
}
```

output:

```
1
8
8
16
```

As per my understanding, during the virtual inheritance every base class will have one vptr so class D is having two vptr and size is 16.

Suppose if the class D also have a virtual funciton assume virtual ~D(). Now the size should be increase to 24(one vptr for D).

But that is not happening.

Some how I misunderstand the virtual ptr concept.

Can anyone explain in clear??

Comment: What?!? Are you sure `sizeof(A) == 1`?

Comment: Seems to be a platform where a `char` is _at least_ 16 bits long if `sizeof(int)` is `1`. What platform are you using?

Comment: when I run this exact code on VC++11 I get 4/12/12/28 which makes much more sense than your output...

Comment: Try creating an instance of your class, then outputting all of the addresses, e.g. `D aD; cout << (A*)&aD << endl; coust << (B*)&aD << endl; ... `.  (It's also worthwhile initializing each of the `int` members with a different value, and doing a hex dump of the object.  You'll recognize the initialize integers, and will see where each object is relative to the entire class.  And what you don't recognize is probably the `vptr`.)

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that your output matches your code. Your output only makes sense if its from a version of your code in which each class did not contain an `int`. Please post the real output.

Comment: Your question actually makes no sense without telling us which compiler you're using. Because what you're asking is heavily implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

`D` needs a vptr, whether it has any virtual functions or not, just as much as `B` and `C` do.

The reason is that the compiler needs a way to get from any instance of `D` to its `A`, `B` or `C`, base class subobjects. Since that inheritance is virtual, some class `E` could come along that derives from `D` but *also* derives from other things with the same virtual bases. The layout of `D` must account for the possibility of that `E` existing.

So, there is no fixed offset to get from a complete object that is an instance of `D` to its base-class subobjects, because of the possibility that this complete object is an instance of the as-yet-undefined `E`.

I'm not sure whether that fully accounts for the behavior you see. I've never used an implementation on which `sizeof(int) == 1`, and I don't really have any grounds to explain why `B` and `D` are 8 and 16.

Answer (score 0):

Why would adding virtual functions to `D` require an additional
`vptr`?  The class image will start with either `B` or `C`, and
`D` can just append its functions to which ever one that is.
(And as soon as you have virtual inheritance, you need some sort
of a pointer, even if there are no virtual functions.)

Adding a virtual function to `A` *will* make a difference
(almost certainly, although of course, everything here is
implementation dependent).  For what it's worth, you might want
to try something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::uintptr_t Word;

class SaveIOFormat
{
    std::basic_ios<char>* myStream;
    char myFill;
    std::basic_ios<char>::fmtflags myFlags;
    int myPrecision;
public:
    SaveIOFormat( std::basic_ios<char>& stream )
        : myStream( &stream )
        , myFill( stream.fill() )
        , myFlags( stream.flags() )
        , myPrecision( stream.precision() )
    {
    }
    ~SaveIOFormat()
    {
        myStream->fill( myFill );
        myStream->flags( myFlags );
        myStream->precision( myPrecision );
    }
};

template <typename T>
class DumpAsWords
{
    Word const* myObj;
    typedef Word const* Iterator;
    typedef char sizeMustBeMultipleOfSizeofWord
            [ sizeof(T) % sizeof(uintptr_t) == 0 ? 1 : -1 ];
    static int const ourLength = sizeof(T) / sizeof(Word);
public:
    DumpAsWords( T const& obj )
        : myObj( reinterpret_cast<Word const*>( &obj ) )
    {
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest,
                                     DumpAsWords const& obj )
    {
        SaveIOFormat saveExcursion( dest );
        dest.fill( '0' );
        dest.setf( std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield );
        for ( Iterator current = obj.myObj, end = obj.myObj + ourLength;
                current != end;
                ++ current ) {
            if ( current != obj.myObj ) {
                dest << ' ';
            }
            dest << std::setw( sizeof(Word) * 2 ) << *current;
        }
        return dest;
    }
};

template <typename T>
DumpAsWords<T>
dump( T const& obj )
{
    return DumpAsWords<T>( obj );
}

class B
{
    Word i;
public:
    B() : i( 1 ) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class L : virtual public B
{
    Word i;
public:
    L() : i( 2 ) {}
};

class R : virtual public B
{
    Word i;
public:
    R() : i( 3 ) {}
};

class D : public L, public R
{
    Word i;
public:
    D() : i( 4 ) {}
};

int
main()
{
    D aD;

    std::cout << "sizeof B: " << sizeof(B) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof L: " << sizeof(L) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof R: " << sizeof(R) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof D: " << sizeof(D) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "addrof B: " << static_cast<B*>( &aD ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addrof L: " << static_cast<L*>( &aD ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addrof R: " << static_cast<R*>( &aD ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addrof D: " << static_cast<D*>( &aD ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "dump: " << dump( aD ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(If it's a little long, it's because I copy/pasted some code
from my libraries to make it simpler and cleaner.)

On my machine, this gives:

```
sizeof B: 16
sizeof L: 32
sizeof R: 32
sizeof D: 56

addrof B: 00000000001AFEB8
addrof L: 00000000001AFE90
addrof R: 00000000001AFEA0
addrof D: 00000000001AFE90

dump: 000000013fb90bb0 0000000000000002 000000013fb90bb8 0000000000000003 0000000000000004 000000013fb90ba8 0000000000000001
```

As you can see, the order is L in D, R in D, D, B (in L, R and
D).  D shares the vptr with L.

(This is compiled with VC++ 11 on a 64 bit Windows machine.  You're results could easily be different.)